# Error installing NS-3 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ns-3

I'm trying to install NS-3 on Ubuntu. I have already updated and installed all the required packages, but when I want to do `build.py` this error occurs:

```
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/ali/Desktop/ns-allinone-3.21/ns-3.21/build'
Build failed
-> task in 'ns3-wave' failed (exit status 1): 
{task 140530495514448: cxx wifi-80211p-helper.cc -> wifi-80211p-
helper.cc.1.o}
['/usr/bin/g++', '-O0', '-ggdb', '-g3', '-Wall', '-Werror', '-Wno-
error=deprecated-declarations', '-fstrict-aliasing', '-Wstrict-aliasing', '-
fPIC', '-pthread', '-I.', '-I..', '-DNS3_ASSERT_ENABLE', '-DNS3_LOG_ENABLE', 
'-DHAVE_SYS_IOCTL_H=1', '-DHAVE_IF_NETS_H=1', '-DHAVE_NET_ETHERNET_H=1', '-
DHAVE_PACKET_H=1', '-DHAVE_SQLITE3=1', '-DHAVE_IF_TUN_H=1', '-DHAVE_GSL=1', 
'../src/wave/helper/wifi-80211p-helper.cc', '-c', '-o', 
'src/wave/helper/wifi-80211p-helper.cc.1.o']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./build.py", line 170, in <module>
sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
File "./build.py", line 161, in main
build_ns3(config, build_examples, build_tests, args, build_options)
File "./build.py", line 81, in build_ns3
run_command([sys.executable, "waf", "build"] + build_options)
File "/home/ali/Desktop/ns-allinone-3.21/util.py", line 24, in run_command
raise CommandError("Command %r exited with code %i" % (argv, retval))
util.CommandError: Command ['/usr/bin/python', 'waf', 'build'] exited with 
code 1
```

What should I do? Please help me, it`s vital for me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from the below link was very much helpful for me.

[Link to Solution](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?s=adf3d552a2b23ae6da2a411f670b785e&p=6252862#post6252862)

**Execute the below commands one by one.**

1. First

```
sudo apt install python3-dev qt5-default libsqlite3-dev 
  libdpdk-dev \libgsl-dev libssh-gcrypt-dev libgtk-3-dev 
  libboost-all-dev \python3-pygraphviz libxml2-dev python3- 
  pip
```

2. `sudo pip3 install pygccxml==2.1.0`
3. `wget` https://www.nsnam.org/release/ns-allinone-3.33.tar.bz2
4. `tar xvf ns-allinone-3.33.tar.bz2`
5. `cd ns-allinone-3.33/`
6. `./build.py`
7. `cd ns-3.33/`
8. `./waf configure --enable-examples`
9. `./waf`

Answer (score 0):

What system are you building? Try with the latest ns-3.27 release and make sure your system is compliant with the requirements (eg. gcc/g++ version)

Answer (score 0):

Build the system in the directory of 'ns-allinone-3.21'. Not in 'ns-3.21'.
Deeplearnning/ns-allinone-3.2$ ./build
Use the manual.
https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/